# File moving in Camel from one directory to another

Tags: file, apache-camel

I am trying file processing in camel version 2.17, my requirement is moving files from one folder to another. If filename have yesterday date. For that I have written java code which fetch yesterday date in `MMddyyyy` format.

I have created below route to move the file, but I having issue in calling `${bean.yesterdayDate}` in `from`. If I run separately the bean I can get the date problem is cannot able to call in from only.

```
<route autoStartup="true" customId="true" id="readingfilesFromfolder">
    <from uri="file://{{baseDirectory}}?move={{file.moved.path}}&amp;scheduler=quartz2&amp;antInclude=*_${bean:yesterdayDate}.xml&amp;scheduler.cron={{moveFile.scheduler}}"/>
    <to uri="mock:result2"/>
    <log message="File Name Named - ${header.CamelFileName} is moved"/>
</route>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `<from>` cannot support dynamic bean method calls in the `antInclude` option. You can use the `filter` option and implement the `GenericFileFilter` interface where you can compute via yesterdays date whether to include the file or not.

See the docs for an example and more details: 
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/file-component.adoc#filter-using-orgapachecamelcomponentfilegenericfilefilter

Comment: Can you please elaborate, I am new to this.Any examples if available.

Comment: See this unit test for an example of a custom filter implementation: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/FileConsumerFileFilterTest.java